# macOS kext with invalid signature

Tags: macos, code-signing, signing, kernel-extension

We have a kext-enabled Developer ID which we are using for code signing and I have verified that the certificate contains the 1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.18 extension required. However, kextutil -tn still shows:

```
Untrusted kexts are not allowed  
Kext with invalid signature (-67050) denied: /Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/A0587A5A-52FC-46DC-832E-81919195902C.kext
```

After signing, I re-extracted the signature using 'codesign -d --extract-certificates' to verify that the correct kext-enabled Developer ID certificate was indeed used during the signing process.

I have "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" and "Developer ID Certification Authority" certs in both the login and System keychains.

Any suggestions on where to go from here? Thanks!

Comment: Is your kext whitelisted in System Preferences?

Comment: No, it is not whitelisted yet as I haven't been prompted to do so. For now, I am just building and signing in XCode then checking the resulting output using kextutil. kextload fails with "system policy prevents loading".

Answer (score 3):

I've figured it out. Turns out macOS 10.13+ denies kexts by default -- even those signed with a valid kex-enabled Dev. ID certificate (which we have). The solution is described in this tech note (and alluded to in the comments above):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2459/_index.html

The first time an attempt is made to load the kext, macOS should present the user with a popup informing them that it was blocked. The user then needs to go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy in order to approve the kext. Note that the approval needs to happen within 30 minutes of the load attempt or it will disappear. Subsequent load attempts will be rejected silently but will reactivate the prompt within "Security & Privacy" -- giving the user another chance to approve the kext.

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.

$ sudo kextutil -v /Users/xxx.yyy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/zzzz-dvqiwdodghcxydamtmpmffakjyrt/Build/Products/Release/zzzz.kext
Defaulting to kernel file '/System/Library/Kernels/kernel'
/Users/xxx.yyy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/zzzz-dvqiwdodghcxydamtmpmffakjyrt/Build/Products/Release/zzzz.kext appears to be loadable (not including linkage for on-disk libraries).
Loading /Users/xxx.yyy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/zzzz-dvqiwdodghcxydamtmpmffakjyrt/Build/Products/Release/zzzz.kext.
/Users/xxx.yyy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/zzzz-dvqiwdodghcxydamtmpmffakjyrt/Build/Products/Release/zzzz.kext successfully loaded (or already loaded).

$ kextstat | grep xxxxxx
161    0 0xffffff7f83af6000 0x3c9000   0x3c9000   com.xxxxxx.driver.zzzz (1) 230E04D6-5C15-373F-8F73-E23566AE3C22 <22 15 5 4 3 1>
```

Comment: i know this is old, but theres another way to bypass this problem? i installed the driver for a usb-to-uart for the ch340c chip and system preference keep bloqing the drivers, i did try all that you said above,  even tryied ```sudo kextload -v usbserial.kext/``` and allow on security and privacy, still no luck